# Substrate Mutate throws an error when updating a member

Tags: rust, substrate

I Have a substrate pallet implementation as follows

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn get_payload)]
pub(super) type Payload<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    Vec<u8>,
    Messages<T>
>;

#[derive(Clone, Decode, Encode, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Messages<T: Config> {

    pub meta: Option<Vec<u8>>,

    pub header: Option<Vec<u8>>,

}

#[pallet::weight(0)]
pub fn update(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    key: Vec<u8>,
    header: Vec<u8>,

) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
    let origin_account = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    let mut payload = Payload::<T>::get(key.clone());
    match payload {
        Some(mut val) => {
            println!("{:?}",val.header);
            <Payload<T>>::mutate(val, val.header=header)
        },
        None => println!("Not found")
    }
```

and in the update function, when I tried to `mutate` it throws the following error

```
the trait `EncodeLike<Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for `Messages<T>`
```

The struct which corresponds to the `Messages` derived from `Encode` and `Decode`.   Documentation is unclear on how to fix this. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct, `Messages<T>` doesn't encode like a `Vec<u8>` and somewhere you try to use `Mesages<T>` where it only takes something that encodes like a `Vec<u8>`.

In `<Payload<T>>::mutate` call: the first argument must be something that encode like `Vec<u8>` and you give a variable of type `Messages<T`, it is an error. instead you probably wants to write `<Payload<T>>::mutate(key.clone, ..)`